# Use the timezone set by the user

Tags: php, timezone, laravel-5.1, mutators

Basically when I get the datetime column in my table I want to adjust its date and time base on the user timezone.

I have this code but it doesn't seem to work, the time never change even though I already change its timezone:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($datetime) {
    $timezone = \Auth::user()->timezone;

    $datetime = $this->asDateTime($value);

    return $datetime->timezone($timezone);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_default_timezone_set()` to set the user timezone.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($datetime) {
    $timezone = \Auth::user()->timezone;

    //Call date_default_timezone_set function to set user timezone or whenever it appropieate
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone); 

    $datetime = $this->asDateTime($value);

    return $datetime->timezone($timezone);
}
```

**Update:**

Also use `Config::set('app.timezone', $timezone)` to change laravel config timezone.

Comment: I already have those setup. Also my original date is: 2016-04-20 03:12:47 and when I dump the result with the timezone functionality, it still gave me the same date. Here are the results [created_at] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-04-20 03:12:47.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Africa/Accra
        )

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to user specified timezone on-thy-fly with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library, which is inside of Laravel already – you don’t need to add or install any packages.
Like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($datetime) {
    return $datetime->timezone(\Auth::user()->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

from : http://laraveldaily.com/timezone-settings-for-created_at-and-similar-fields/?utm_source=tuicool&utm_medium=referral